# Where do I find my credentials for using watsonx.ai

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, large-language-model

I am trying to run a basic example using the [ibm-generative-ai](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-generative-ai) library

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from genai.client import Client
from genai.credentials import Credentials
from genai.schema import (
    TextGenerationParameters,
    TextGenerationReturnOptions,
)


def heading(text: str) -> str:
    """Helper function for centering text."""
    return "\n" + f" {text} ".center(80, "=") + "\n"


# make sure you have a .env file under genai root with
# GENAI_KEY=<your-genai-key>
# GENAI_API=<genai-api-endpoint>
load_dotenv()
client = Client(credentials=Credentials.from_env())

print(heading("Simple Text Generation"))
# yields batch of results that are produced asynchronously and in parallel
for response in client.text.generation.create(
    model_id="google/flan-t5-xl",
    inputs=["What is a molecule?", "What is NLP?"],
    parameters=TextGenerationParameters(
        max_new_tokens=150,
        min_new_tokens=20,
        return_options=TextGenerationReturnOptions(
            input_text=True,
        ),
    ),
):
    result = response.results[0]
    print(f"Input Text: {result.input_text}")
    print(f"Generated Text: {result.generated_text}")
    print("")
```

The [documentation](https://ibm.github.io/ibm-generative-ai/v2.1.1/faq.html#which-api-endpoint-should-i-use) does not tell me precisely where to find the api endpoint that I need. Can someone provide additional information on this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that to this point the SDK cannot be used with watsonx.ai  https://github.com/IBM/ibm-generative-ai/issues/322